# Regex to find or extract strings between the "<>" angle brackets

Tags: php, regex, email

In the following string,

```
Jason <jason@bigcreative.com>
```

how can I extract the part inside the angle brackets?

I tried `<\w>` and it didn't work.

Ideas?

I'm using `preg_match()` in PHP if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `<(.*?)>` as regex, then.

Comment: Use `<([^>]+)>`. It'll be faster.

Answer (score 22):

user502515 has already given the regex you want.

I'd like to add why your regex `<\w>` did not work:

`\w` is the short for the character class `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` and matches any **one** character from that class. To match more characters you need to use quantifiers:

- `+` for one or more and
- `*` for zero or more

Since you want to extract the string matching the pattern you need to enclose the pattern in parenthesis `(..)` so that it gets captured.

Now your original task was to extract the string between `<..>`, the regex `<(\w+)>` will not do the job as the char class `\w` does not include `@`.

To match anything you use the regex `.*` which matches any arbitrary string (without newline).

So the regex `<(.*)>` matches and captures any string between the angular brackets.

The match is greedy, so if the input string is `foo<foo@foo.com>, bar<bar.com>` you'll be extracting `foo@foo.com>, bar<bar.com`. To fix this you make the match non-greedy by adding a `?` at the end of `.*` giving us the correct regex `<(.*?)>`

Comment: This is the kind of quality answer that, while it doesn't specifically answer the specific question directly, deserves upvotes for being especially helpful by explaining *why*. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

To get a match between the `<` char and the next closest `>`, with no `<` and `>` in between (note `<.*?>` [matches strings](https://regex101.com/r/m1sSnA/2) like `<..<...>`), you can use

```py
<([^<>]*)>
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/m1sSnA/1).

*Regex details*:

- `<` - a `<` char
- `([^<>]*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than `<` and `>`
- `>` - a `>` char.

**Code examples**

- [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) - `var res = Regex.Matches(text, @"<([^<>]*)>").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value).ToList();`
- [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) - `const matches = [...Array.from(text.matchAll(/<([^<>]*)>/g), x => x[1])]`
- [php](/questions/tagged/php) - `$res = preg_match_all('~<([^<>]*)>~', $text, $matches) ? $matches[1] : "";`
- [python](/questions/tagged/python) - `res = re.findall(r'<([^<>]*)>', text)`